# Display duplicate records in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that has about 30k records, of which 2k I estimate are duplicate.

How do I craft a query to show duplicates that share ALL of the following columns STREET_NUMBER, STREET_NAME, UNIT_NUMBER, ZIP_CODE but another column called MLS_ID that are NOT the same?

I only want to see the records where there is a complete match and the MLS_ID is different.

Comment: Should the last sentence say "I want the records where there is a complete match **EXCEPT FOR** the MLS_ID"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work (untested)

```
SELECT *  
  FROM Table1 T
 INNER JOIN
          (
            SELECT STREET_NUMBER, STREET_NAME, UNIT_NUMBER, ZIP_CODE
              FROM Table1 T1
             GROUP BY STREET_NUMBER, STREET_NAME, UNIT_NUMBER, ZIP_CODE
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT MLS_ID) > 1
          ) T2 ON T.STREET_NUMBER = T2.STREET_NUMBER AND T.STREET_NAME = T2.STREET_NAME AND         T.UNIT_NUMBER = T2.UNIT_NUMBER AND T.ZIP_CODE = T2.ZIP_CODE
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a group-by, and take only those groups where the count is greater than 1 (i.e. where there are duplicates):

```
select 
  <grouping columns>  -- put STREET_NUMBER, STREET_NAME, etc. here
from
  (select distinct * from <tablename>)
group by
  <grouping columns>  -- and here!
having 
  count(*) > 1
```

Just **don't** put `MLS_ID` in the group-by clause.  This assumes that `MLS_ID` is the only non-grouping column.

Answer (score 1):

Try this(untested):

```
SELECT * FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 
  USING(STREET_NUMBER, STREET_NAME, UNIT_NUMBER, ZIP_CODE) 
  WHERE t1.MLS_ID != t2.MLS_ID;
```

Comment: If we have 3 different records with different MLS_ID but same street_number,streetname etc. Then this query will return 6 records ... I havent tested it but, that seems logical .....